# Android ime options not working

Tags: android, android-edittext, imeoptions

I am trying to set up a listener for the android ime options, that stores the value of the `EditText` in the shared preferences. I have it set up like so, but when I press the "return" key on my keyboard, nothing happens and it never goes into the listener. Any ideas on why I'm doing wrong?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);

    mDone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done);
    mTemperature = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.temperature);

    mDone.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

            int action = event.getAction();
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                // Do whatever you want here
                SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();

                int updateSweater = Integer.parseInt(mTemperature.getText().toString());
                edit.remove("sweater");
                edit.putInt("sweater", updateSweater);
                edit.commit();
                preferences.getInt("sweater", 0);

                Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Sweater Weather Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

This is how I set up my EditText

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/temperature"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@color/gray"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:hint="Farenheit"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:imeOptions="actionDone"/>
```

Comment: How did you define mDone?

Comment: @GuilhermeP I have added more code for context

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is not working because `setOnEditorActionListener` should be defined to your `EditText` (and not to your Button).

```
mTemperature = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.temperature);

mTemperature.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {

        int action = event.getAction();
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            // Do whatever you want here
            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor edit = preferences.edit();

            int updateSweater = Integer.parseInt(mTemperature.getText().toString());
            edit.remove("sweater");
            edit.putInt("sweater", updateSweater);
            edit.commit();
            preferences.getInt("sweater", 0);

            Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Sweater Weather Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            Intent intent = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

If you need to take any action after click in `mDone`, it is better to set a `ClickListener` to `mDone`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to do mTemperature.setOnEditorActionListener since it is the EditText. Also, check for null on event, actionId can be equal to EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE when event is null.

Answer (score 0):

imeOptions will not work for multiple lines EditText.

Change it to single line.

set below parameter in your xml file:

android:singleLine="true"